# Navbar appearing on 2 lines instead of one

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want the navbars to appear in a single line. I coded as it was explained in jQuery mobile website. However the 2 `<li>` are appearing in two lines.

```
<head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta name="language" content="en" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.css" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
```

```
<body>
            <ul data-role="navbar" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" role="navigation" class="ui-navbar ui-mini">
                <li><a href="HolidayList.html" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Holiday List</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Closed Locations</a></li>           
            </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you missing the main div above nav bar.

As you can see here in [demo](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html). Your code should be as like below.

```
<div data-role="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="a.html" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="b.html">Two</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
```